# Как правильнее организовать схему таблиц для БД?

Tags: база-данных, таблицы

Я разрабатываю БД для спа-салона и возникла такая проблема. У меня есть таблица клиентов, таблица сотрудников и таблицы аккаунтов клиентов и сотрудников отдельно. Я столкнулся с проблемой того, что мне нужно определять роль аккаунта. Я думал создать общую таблицу, но тогда будет обращовываться цикл из таблиц (посмотреть можно на изображении), а это вроде как неправильно. Подскажите, как поступить в данной ситуации.[image: Схема таблиц]

Comment: не знаю что именно вы там называете циклом, но аккаунты надо свести в одну таблицу. Можете туда добавить поле обозначающее тип записи клиент/сотрудник. Хотя с другой стороны ничто не мешает сотруднику оказаться в числе клиентов. Как в целом и наоборот.

Comment: Циклы, как я понял, это ситуация, когда таблицы в бд связаны так, что образуют замкнутый круг. Т.е., если создавать здесь общую таблицу Аккаунты, то цикл будет Аккаунты-Клиенты-Записи-Сотрудники-Аккаунты.

Comment: и что из этого? Кто вам сказал что это неправильно? Вот разделить на две тут точно неправильно